# jQuery on click but not on child click

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to create a small 20x20px div box, that when clicked opens a 200x200px box located inside the first box:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
    <div id="box" style="display:none;width:200px; height:200px;">
        <img src="example1.gif" />
        <img src="example2.gif" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Aim**

My aim is to make it so when `#container` is clicked, `#box` is faded in. The user will then click an image inside this box and the `#box` will then fade out.

1. `#container` clicked and `#box` `fadeIn();`
2. Item in `#box` is clicked
3. `#box` `fadeOut()`

To do this I am using the following jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", "#container", function(){

    $("#box").fadeIn("fast");
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", "#box", function(){

    $("#box").fadeOut("fast");
});

$(document).on("click", "#box img", function(){

    // Do things, removed for example

    $("#box").fadeOut();        
});
```

**What actually happens**

At the moment it's not working though because this happens:

1. Click `#container`
2. `#box` fades in
3. Click `#box img`
4. // Do things, removed for example
5. `#box` fades out
6. `#box` fades in

Number 6. on the above list should not happen, the box should not fade back in.

I think the problem is with `.on("click", "#container", function(){` this may be applying that code when `#container #box img` is clicked, how can I stop this?

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/8FuBD/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).  The event is bubbling up which is causing the div to fade in again.

```
$(document).on("click", "#box img", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    // Do things, removed for example

    $("#box").fadeOut();        
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ycpFL/

Comment: I'm sure I tried exactly this but it didn't work earlier ... works now though, sods laws, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change your last part to use [`event.stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) so that the event does not bubble up to the `#box` element.

```
$(document).on("click", "#box img", function(e){

    // Do things, removed for example
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#box").fadeOut();        
});
```

Comment: Thanks, answer works but the other guy has less points so I'll give him some :) Should `e.stopPropagation();` come before or after `// Do things, removed for example` because that's the only difference?

Comment: You should stop propagation immediately. This will prevent any possible scenario of event bubbling.